# Why am i receiving this (error: TS2376) while running oak.? Details of error in body

Tags: typescript, backend, deno, oak

I have this simple server.ts file.

```
import { Application, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();
const router = new Router();

router
.get("/",(ctx) => {
  ctx.response.body = "Router has been created";
  // Implement your code
  });

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());
app.listen({port:8000});
```

I run this app with command:

```
deno run --allow-net server.ts
```

It throws this error:

```
error: TS2376 [ERROR]: A 'super' call must be the first statement in the constructor when a class contains initialized properties, parameter properties, or private identifiers.
  constructor(
  ^
    at https://deno.land/x/oak@v7.4.0/range.ts:102:3
```

I just want to use deno with oak instead of fighting with internal deno stuff. Is there any thing i am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Deno are you using? There was a little bug in 1.9.0 that caused this error to randomly happen

Comment: @StevenGuerrero It is deno v 1.8.3

Answer (score 2):

Am also experiencing the same after upgrading deno to 1.9.2 then back to lower versions 1.6.2 1.6.0 1.8.3

Just upgrade your version to 1.9.2. You will be sorted